# VS 2013 IntelliSense disabling itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

my intelliSense in VS2013 disables by random maybe every once a workday and I have to restart VS to make it work again. It doesn't show up even when explicitly pushing ctrl + space. Maybe I inavertently push some key combination to disable it.

It just isn't such a deal to restart VS but it would be great if somebody helped me and others with this.

I don't have ReSharper installed (as I've found in some related topic has some effect on intelliSense)

Comment: I've had a similar experience in the past with two scenarios; sometimes individual files lose it, so I just close and reopen the file.  Other times, it seems like hotkeys are stuck because if I hit ctrl everything goes back to normal.

Comment: How about this devenv /resetuserdata.

Comment: It might work, I'll wait till it happens again, is there a way to start devenv from the IDE GUI?

Comment: It might be a crazy idea. But why don't you disable an anti-virus app if any.

Comment: I have seen this too. Now, that I finally leanrned about enforcing it with ctrl-blank it has gone away..?